# Change margin points in leftmargin of exam class

Tags: exam

How do I put the points on the leftmargin more to the left? Tried even changing some code in `exam.cls` but I failed.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\printanswers

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
%   \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
%   \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
%   \setlength{\marginpointssep}{120pt}%
%   \setlength{\labelwidth}{20pt}
}

\pointformat{/\themarginpoints}
\pointsinmargin
\setlength{\labelwidth}{2cm}

\begin{questions}
\question[3]Answer this question.

\question[3]Answer these questions.
    \hspace{2cm}\begin{parts}
        \part[10]
    Is this a question?
        \part[10]
        Is this a question?
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]`

Comment: try `\pointformat{/\themarginpoints\hspace{1cm}}`